# Can someone help me remember how to do this Geometry question?

Tags: geometry

[image]

I really need help remembering what theorem to use and how to use it. Thanks!

Comment: Use the law of sines. [just google it for how to use]

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), it is searchable while pictures aren't.

Comment: Diagrams are fine though.

Answer (score 2):

In a triangle, longest side is the one opposite the largest angle.

In $\triangle KMP$, the largest angle is $\angle M$. So KP (side opposite to $\angle M$) must be the largest side.

In $\triangle KPR$, the largest angle is $\angle K$. So PR must be the largest side. As such PR > KP.

Combining the two statements above, it's clear PR is the longest segment.